# Questionnaire For Android and iPhone

Tags: java, android, iphone, objective-c, ios

I have an **Experience of only 6 months on iPhone and Android** and I have to take **Telephone Interview** of a **4-5 Years of Experience Guy** as my senior is on Leave. So can someone please tell me **some links** to find nice questions (if possible with answers) or tell me **some Good Questions** to ask. I will try to find the correct answers of them by myself.

Comment: REading your appeal I will not downvote or close BTW a question can be Lifecycle of Android app not Activity I myself dont know the answer this has been asked when I faced an interview :P

Comment: How are you, rookie (no offense meant), supposed to evaluate an experienced professional? Simply reading out loud questions from the paper and comparing his answers to those on paper isn't going to work.

Comment: I had come across similar issue a week ago. No problems. Just ask him to explain about his apps and try to question him about the functionality of those apps as much as u can. Before that, u try to install the apps done by him (from the stores)in ur phone so that u get an idea what the app is... thats it

Comment: @ingsaurabh, Sergei Tulentsev, Seshu Vinay :- Thanks a Lot Guys... Whatever u told me i will keep that in my mind.... Sorry for such a stupid Quesiton. :)

Comment: You do realize that the iPhone SDK only went into beta in 2008, so unless they worked at Apple or in the early jailbreak community, they are lying if they say they have 5 years of iOS experience. That could be a good candidate filter right there.

Comment: @Brad :- Great, presence of mind sir, Actually she had written that she was working in Mobile domain from 5 past years and was working on iOS from past 3 years... but i was in hurry so couldn't present it in a correct way here. Well finally, my question is downvoted and closed for the first time :(

Comment: http://www.corejavaandroidinterviewquestionsexperiencedprofessionals.org

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better you first of all study his resume and ask questions pertaining to the projects done by him. As the guy is having exp of 4-5 years,he must have gone through all aspects hopefully so you can ask him something like what kind of projects he has worked on till date. Also whether he has worked on OpenGL or not and what so ever.

Comment: Also check this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087528/objective-c-iphone-developer-interview-questions

Comment: @ sarah :- Thnx for ur nice response.

Comment: Also you can mark the and as correct and close the question.

Comment: hehee ok i will.. by the way getting 35 Points for a simple Question....is good na.. :)) Nice Question gets only 5.. :(

Comment: Well...it's upon the luck and the efforts made..!! :)